# Convertendo um algoritmo .NET para JS

Tags: javascript, .net, algoritmo, visual-basic-6

Amigos, estou com um pequeno problema na 'conversão' de um algoritmo.
No algoritmo em `.net` eu tenho a seguinte estrutura condicional:

```
if (')' == caracter){
    String item = pilha.Pop().ToString();
    while (!item.Equals("(")){
        resultado += item;
        item = pilha.Pop().ToString();
    }
}
```

Jogando tudo para `javaScript` ficaria do seguinte modo:

```
if (')' == caracter){
    var item = pilha.pop();
    while (item != '('){
        resultado += item; //Corrigido
        item = pilha.pop();
    }
}
```

No meu entender `while (!item.Equals("(")){` seria o equivalente a um `while (item != '('){`

So que nessa condição ele está entrando em looping infinito, ou seja o algoritmo não está executando da maneira como deveria..... Alguem poderia me dar um Help sobre a função `Equals` e o operador `!` em `.net`?

A minha interpretação foi "muito" errônea?

-------Interpretacao do codigo todo:
`.NET`

```
private String funcao(String expressao){
    String resultado = null;
    Stack pilha = new Stack();
    char caracter;
    int prioridade = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < expressao.Length; i++){
        caracter = expressao[i];

        if(IsOperando(caracter)){
            resultado += caracter;
        }else if (IsOperador(caracter)){
            prioridade = ObterPrioridade(caracter);
            while((pilha.Count != 0) && (ObterPrioridade(Convert.ToChar(pilha.Peek())) >= prioridade)){
                resultado += pilha.Pop().ToString();
            }

            pilha.Push(caracter);
        }else if ('(' == caracter){
            pilha.Push(caracter);
        }else if (')' ==caracter){
            String item = pilha.Pop().ToString();
            while (!item.Equals("(")){
                resultado += item;
                item = pilha.Pop().ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    while(pilha.Count != 0){
        resultado += pilha.Pop().ToString();
    }

    return resultado;
}
```

Interpretado pra `JS`:

```
function funcao(){
    var arrayDeCaracteres = "((A + B) * C – (D – E)) ^ (F – G)";
    var pilha = new Array;
    var prioridade = 0;
    var caracter = ""; var resultado = "";

    for(i = 0; i < arrayDeCaracteres.length; i++){
        caracter = arrayDeCaracteres[i];

        if(operando(caracter)){
            resultado += caracter;
        }else if (operador(caracter)){
            prioridade = obterPrioridade(caracter);
            aux = pilha.pop();
            aux2 = obterPrioridade(aux);
            pilha.push(aux);
            while((pilha.length  > 1) && (obterPrioridade(aux2 >= prioridade))){
                resultado += pilha.pop();
            }
            //Insere o objeto no topo da pilha
            pilha.push(caracter);
        }else if ('(' == caracter){
            //Insere o objeto no topo da pilha
            pilha.push(caracter);
        }else if (')' == caracter){
            var item = pilha.pop();
            while (item != '('){
                resultado += item;
                //Recupera e remove o objeto do topo da pilha
                item = pilha.pop();
            }
        }
    }

    while(pilha.length > 1){
        resultado += pilha.pop();
    }
}
```

Funções `ObterPrioridade`, `IsOperando` e `IsOperador` em `.NET`:

```
private int ObterPrioridade(char caracter){
    int retorno= 0;
    String pri2 = "+-";
    String pri3 = "*/";
    if('(' == caracter){
        retorno = 1;
    }else if(pri2.IndexOf(caracter) >= 0) {
        retorno = 2;
    }else if(pri3.IndexOf(caracter) >= 0){
        retorno = 3;
    }else if ('^' == caracter){
        retorno = 4;
    }
    return retorno;
}

private bool IsOperando(char caracter){
    String letras = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVXZ";
    return (letras.IndexOf(caracter) >= 0);
}

private bool IsOperador(char caracter){
    String operadores = "+-*/^";
    return (operadores.IndexOf(caracter) >= 0);
}
```

Funções `obterPrioridade`, `operando` e `operador` em `JS`:

```
function operando(caracter){
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z]+$/;
    if(regex.test(caracter)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function operador(caracter){
    var regex = /^[*+-–/]+$/gi;
    if(regex.test(caracter)){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function obterPrioridade(caracter){
    var retorno= 0;
    var regex1 = /^[+-–]+$/gi;
    var regex2 = /^[*/]+$/gi;

    if('(' == caracter){
        retorno = 1;
    }else if(regex1.test(caracter)){
        retorno = 2;
    }else if(regex2.test(caracter)){
        retorno = 3;
    }else if ('^' == caracter){
        retorno = 4;
    }
    return retorno;
}
```

EXPLICAÇÃO DO ALGORITMO:

O algoritmo prevê a conversão de uma expressão matemática InFixa em PosFixa....

O que ser uma **expressão InFixa**?

Expressões naturais, como normalmente são escritas, tipo: `( a + b ) * ( c - d )`

O que ser uma **expressão PosFixa**?

Expressões onde os operadores são posicionados após as operações de forma que os parenteses não são necessáriosa, tipo a b + c d - *

Tem regra de prioridade de operadores e tudo o mais, é bem complicadinho, mas o algoritmo é um tanto quanto simples

Comment: O que tem essa array `pilha`?

Comment: está empilhando operadores do tipo " +-*/ " alem de caracteres " () "

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo? Qual é a `pilha.length`? Se um dos elementos dessa array não tiver o `(` esse loop vai ser infinito mesmo

Comment: Cara, rodei os dois aqui e deu certo. Só tem q tomar cuidado se alguma vez vai aparecer o '(', pq ai entra num loop infinito.

Comment: Então, `!item.Equals("(")` seria o mesmo que `item != '('` mesmo?

Comment: Sim... a mesma coisa.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio esse código parece-me frágil. Daí eu pedir exemplos para ajudar a optimizar. De resto a sua "tradução" entre linguagens parece-me correta tirando o facto de `resultado` na sua versão ter somente o valor da ultima iteração e não uma concatenação das iterações.

Comment: So complementando o que eu disse antes, é a mesma coisa para este tipo de aplicação.

Comment: Na verdade o que vai acontecer ai é que quando a pilha não tiver o caractere que você está comparando, um hora, o loop vai pedir o pop() de uma lista vazia e, então, vai dar erro.

Comment: Vou passar o algoritmo completo pra teste

Comment: Pronto.... tem algumas funções de .Net como o Peek(que bem se não me engano, inclusive, é uma classe extra) que não são nativas do JS, por isso fiz meio que uma gambiarra ali, e preferi trabalhar com `RegEx` pra descobrir se é operando ou operador

Comment: A, e @Sergio valeu pelo toque, corrigi ali a ultima iteração pra concatenar o valor do item

Comment: Equal é usado para comparar objetos enquanto o operador !=
é usado para comparar tipos Primitivos.

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver usando o IE ou alguns outros browsers que não implementam corretamente isso, esta expressão não vai funcionar:

```
 caracter = expressao[i];  // nem sempre funciona
```

O resultado desta expressão no IE é `undefined`.
Em Javascript, você deve usar a expressão:

```
 caracter = expressao.charAt(i); // sempre funciona
```

Também, invés de construir arrays assim:

```
 var pilha = new Array; // funciona, mas não é legal...
                        // alguém ainda vai editar e dar um
                        //  new Array(32) ou Array(32, 3) e entender tudo errado!
```

Faça assim:

```
 var pilha = []; // funcionar e você pode inicializar tranquilamente!
```

Quem está acostumado com javascript, a segunda expressão é muito mais simples e legível. Também você verá que é muito comum iniciar arrays em javascript com valores já. Usar a primeira expressão `new Array()` com parâmetros leva a muitos resultados errôneos, pois a ordem e quantidade de parâmetros usam construtores nada óbvios!

No mais a "tradução" está ok!